# Perl brace regex takes expontial time to parse

Tags: regex, performance, perl

I have a perl script which is taking exponential time to parse a regex based on the length of the string being parsed.  The code is as follows:

```
$BRACE_MATCH = qr/ (?: [^\(\)]+ | \((??{$BRACE_MATCH})\))* /x;
$expr="(abcdef || abcdefghijklmno)"
timethis(1, sub {$expr =~ /^($BRACE_MATCH)\|\|($BRACE_MATCH)$/});
```

This takes 8 seconds to run.  If I add another letter to the string, it takes 16.  Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Regular expressions are used for finding specific patterns of characters, not determining offsets. There are plenty of functions related to determining the length of strings...are you set on using regex?

Comment: Why you have `*` at the end of your regexp?

Comment: Does changing `[^\(\)]+` to `[^\(\)]++` and `(?:...)*` to `(?:...)*+` help?

Comment: Can you please post the content of `$BRACE_MATCH`?

Comment: @Krishnachandra Sharma, he did

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma its recursive.

Comment: Dunno what your regex is matching for, but your `$expr` does not match it, give us a description what you are checking for.

Comment: @PSIAlt, Still, shouldn't take 22s to determine it doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ikegami said, the reason it takes so long is that there's an exponential number of ways that the pattern can divide the string into chunks.  To get it to work efficiently in Perl's regex engine, you have to limit the backtracking.

You can do that with the `++` possessive quantifier.  That limits backtracking by saying that it's all or nothing.  But to make it work, you have to be careful about what it's matching.

The reason that `[^()]++` doesn't work (you don't need the backslashes there, parens aren't special inside a character class) is that it also matches `|`, which is a character your bigger regex is looking for.  You need to be able to backtrack over `|`, but not over other characters (because splitting the string at a character other than `(` `)` or `|` won't help the regex match).

Try this:

```
$BRACE_MATCH = qr/ (?: [^()|]++ | \| | \((??{$BRACE_MATCH})\))* /x;
```

This says that `$BRACE_MATCH` is a sequence of any number of 3 things:

1. A string of characters other than `()|` (which will be backtracked over as a single chunk)
2. A `|` character
3. A balanced `(...)` expression

The reason that

```
$BRACE_MATCH = qr/ (?: [^()]++ | \((??{$BRACE_MATCH})\))* /x;
```

doesn't match `(XX || YY) || ZZ` is that there's whitespace after the `)`.  That whitespace gets matched by the `[^()]++` part, but that also matches the rest of the string (because there are no more parens) and then won't give part of it back (because it's a possessive quantifier).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are many possibilities the engine must try before it can determine that none of them match.

Perl's engine is designed to be good at avoiding unnecessary backtracking (even at the cost of matching a bit slower than other engines), but the optimisations apparently can't help you here.

So what you need to do is reduce the amount of backtracking, and that's very easy to do.

```
our $BRACE_MATCH = qr/ (?> (?: [^()]+ | \( (??{ $BRACE_MATCH }) \) )* ) /x;
                       ^^^                                            ^
```

Or as I suggested in the comments two hours ago:

```
our $BRACE_MATCH = qr/ (?: [^()]++ | \( (??{ $BRACE_MATCH }) \) )*+ /x;
                                 ^                                ^
```

With either of these changes, the test takes 0 seconds instead of 22.

---

By the way, you might want to look into using `(?PARNO)`

> Similar to `(??{ code })` except it does not involve compiling any code

Comment: Thanks.  I'm fairly new to perl, so I don't know all of the tricks yet.

Comment: Sorry, I had to retract my accept -- once I put the ++ in, it will not match: `(XX || YY) || ZZ`...  (I'm looking to match any expression which has an || not in brackets...).

Comment: That's cause $BRACE_MATCH matches stuff it shouldn't. That's an unrelated problem.